# Color another cell based on (if blank) by two different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, colors

I had this working at one point

- Column A:  Names
- Column B:  Date
- Column C:  Date
- IF Column B cell is filled, Color Fill ColumnA-Cell GREEN
- IF Column C is filled, Color Fill ColumnA-Cell is RED
- Column C overrides all.
- If Column B is Filled, AND Column C is filled it will be RED.

Comment: "I had this working at one point" - did it stopped working? How exactly? Have you changed anything in the worksheet? Can you post some screenshots? Your current question contains way too few information for any useful help.

Comment: What's the meaning of "Column C overrides all"?

Comment: Someone removed all the formulas, I no longer had them to compare to.

If Column C is filled it's red.
It's access to program if that helps to understand the situation.

Tom was given access -date- now his name is green as a person who has access, 
Access is no longer given -date- Now his name is red.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

In the format bar, use the formula `=ISNUMBER(B2)` and set the format to green. Add a new rule, and set the formula to `=ISNUMBER(C2)` and set the format to red. Make sure the conditional formatting for red is above the formatting condition for green, as below.

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to worry about the order of formatting conditions, you could change the green formatting formula to `=AND(ISNUMBER(B2), NOT(ISNUMBER(C2)))`